# How to implement Selenium webdriver for web application developed with React.js components

Tags: html, reactjs, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am working with Selenium automation and the appliction I am testing is based on react.js technology and it has so many dynamic contents. Because of this I never find ID or Name of any element. Always I have to search with Text contains. Also It has table based on react.js and there is not table, tr or td componet

i.e xpath of one of cell:"//*

```
[@id='react']/div/div/span/span/span/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]".
```

I always found similar xpath for button, select drop down or any element. Does anyone help me with this react.js implementation?

It become hard to find dynamic elements and locate this elements.
Also, it become imposible to get check box state;
When checkbox checked:

```
<span class="MuiButtonBase-root-203 MuiIconButton-root-270 MuiSwitchBase-root-295 MuiSwitchBase-default-297 MuiCheckbox-default-292 MuiSwitchBase-checked-298 MuiCheckbox-checked-293">
<span class="MuiIconButton-label-276">
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-279" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
<input class="MuiSwitchBase-input-296" value="on" type="checkbox">
</span>
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-205"></span>
```

When checkbox not checked:

```
<span class="MuiButtonBase-root-203 MuiIconButton-root-270 MuiSwitchBase-root-295 MuiSwitchBase-default-297 MuiCheckbox-default-292">
<span class="MuiIconButton-label-276">
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-279" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
<input class="MuiSwitchBase-input-296" value="on" type="checkbox">
</span>
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-205"></span>
```

Anyone has idea? How to read check box and entire table?

I have three check boxes (Text1, Text2 and Text3). Lables Text1 and so are dynamically changed based on previous selection..Now from this I want check the status of check box and do appropriate action

```
<span class="MuiButtonBase-root-461 MuiIconButton-root-528 MuiSwitchBase-root-553 MuiSwitchBase-default-555 MuiCheckbox-default-550">
<span class="MuiIconButton-label-534">
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-537" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
<path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"/>
</svg>
<input class="MuiSwitchBase-input-554" value="on" type="checkbox"/>
</span>
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-463"/>
</span>
<p class="MuiTypography-root-1 MuiTypography-body1-10 MuiFormControlLabel-label-549">Text1</p>


<label class="MuiFormControlLabel-root-546 MuiFormControlLabel-hasLabel-548">
<span class="MuiButtonBase-root-461 MuiIconButton-root-528 MuiSwitchBase-root-553 MuiSwitchBase-default-555 MuiCheckbox-default-550">
<span class="MuiIconButton-label-534">
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-537" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
<input class="MuiSwitchBase-input-554" value="on" type="checkbox"/>
</span>
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-463"/>
</span>
<p class="MuiTypography-root-1 MuiTypography-body1-10 MuiFormControlLabel-label-549">Text2</p>


<span class="MuiButtonBase-root-461 MuiIconButton-root-528 MuiSwitchBase-root-553 MuiSwitchBase-default-555 MuiCheckbox-default-550">
<span class="MuiIconButton-label-534">
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-537" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
<input class="MuiSwitchBase-input-554" value="on" type="checkbox"/>
</span>
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-463"/>
</span>
<p class="MuiTypography-root-1 MuiTypography-body1-10 MuiFormControlLabel-label-549">Text3</p>
```

Comment: One more thing, I so many elements with same name class name and thier title, name along with check box are dynamically generated

Comment: Would development be willing to implement HTML id attributes as hooks?

Answer (score 0):

### Use Xpath-contains instead of string-contains

- Shorten your xpath by using `//tag[contains(@attr, 'string')]`
  for example `//spans[contains(@class, 'MuiCheckbox-checked')]`

### Code Solution(Level-by-Level)

- First, select high-level elements
- Then, find your second-level elements(i.e. Button)

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mentioned that on page has many same elements. LIke pages consists multiple check boxes and their name, titles side to that have dynamic names. I dont know how to handle this scenarion

Comment: Cloud you please provide an example url to your site? I have no ideas about the way they behave. (Dynamic elements)

Comment: Added in main question as comment was too long